# Dell Inspiron 5523 does not boot ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, ubuntu-18.04

i have a problem installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 alongside with windows 10 after boot and choice try ubuntu or install ubuntu gives me a blank screen.

i try many solutions

change IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers to AHCI

disable Secure Boot

boot UEFI

add no splash, nomodeset, and nouveau.modeset=0 to grub

Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz

Display Adapters : Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 + NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M

IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers : Standard SATA AHCI Controller

best regards

Comment: The parameter to add, if needed, it's just `nomodeset` . No need to change anything else (and "no splash" isn't a valid parameter).

Comment: i try it and same

Comment: So, make sure you're booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: And for better results, if you have that possibility in the firmware (UEFI) select the onboard graphics (Intel) / disable Nvidia.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes i'm sure booting from UEFI , and try your solution but i don't have the option to disable integrated graphics

Comment: I would redo the USB, at this point. If you're doing it from Windows, with Rufus, make sure the options GPT/UEFI are selected before burning the ISO.

Comment: Same blank screen

Comment: Have you verified the ISO? It could be corrupt... Other than that I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: I try many iso's fedora , Ubuntu 18.04 16.04 , and I'm sure iso burn right, it's working on Lenovo PC

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you out but if you log in as root in emergency mode and try typing `journalctl -b` you get the logs of the boot, i don't know if ubuntu shows them on startup, Debian does.. You should look at these logs to determine where is the problem.
Otherwise try reinstalling, maybe the installation is corrupted it happens with linux, sometimes you have to reinstall to get everything working. Back up your data!

Comment: i don't know how login as root, i don't install OS yet root login after installing i think